# NeoVim not loading init.vim file

Tags: neovim

I just installed Neovim and created a simple init.vim file (located at HOME/.config/nvim/init.vim), and when I do `:source %` the script works, but when I exit and reopen Neovim, the file doesn't get loaded and I get the normal Neovim without the configurations I added to the file... How can I let Neovim load init.vim?

Comment: When asking questions, always include the relevant information. In this case, your system, nvim version, etc. Do not make guess what your environment is. You get a better chance of being answered.

Comment: The path `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` working for me without sourcing, I guess more information need to provide.

Comment: Adding a note as it may be useful for other users: it can also happen when using sudo as the `init.vim` file path is not the same.

Answer (score 8):

Try to run Neovim with `-V` option, which will dump the startup log to the given file:

```
nvim -V /tmp/nvim.log
```

Then open the created log file and carefully read the lines. It's hard to say what could be wrong there, but you may see which configuration files were loaded and, perhaps, the warnings when reading some files.

For example, my log file contains the following line:

```
continuing in /home/jubnzv/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

Which mean that `init.vim` was loaded.

Try to find the similar line in your log. If you don't see it, please check the filepath and permissions for the configuration file.

Comment: the first lines seem to indicate the problem:
```could not source "$VIM\sysinit.vim"
could not source "C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim"
sourcing "C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.vim"
not found in runtime path: "ftdetect/*.vim"
not found in runtime path: "ftdetect/*.lua"
```
but still, i don't know how to fix this....

Comment: What is the absolute path to your configuration file? You should put it in `C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim`.

Comment: it's C:\Users\filip\.config\nvim\init.vim.... i guess i'll move it to `C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim`

Comment: Yes, please move it.

Answer (score 2):

In MacOS I found the following error after running `nvim -V /tmp/nvim.log`(as in @jubnzv's answer):

> E5422: Conflicting configs: "/Users/lernerzhang/.config/nvim/init.lua" "/Users/lernerzhang/.config/nvim/init.vim"

Then I kept the init.vim and deleted init.lua, and moved the content of init.lua file to `~/.config/nvim/lua/config.lua` and sourced the config.lua file in init.vim by adding this line into it:

```
lua require('config')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux based OS then init.vim or init.lua file should be under `$HOME/.config/NVIM/init.vim`

In windows OS it should be under
`C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim`

`:source %` Works because it forces NVIM to source file opened in current buffer.